# psycopg2 Python concatenate percentage '%' in field postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This is a pretty specific question, but I'm running an automated script through Python that runs a Postgresql query using psycopg2. One of the fields returns percentages, but instead of showing them as a whole number, I want to show add a percentage after each number. For instance, I have this line in my query:

```
CASE WHEN (delivered_orders != 0) then round((scanned_deliveries::numeric 
/ delivered_orders::numeric)*100) when delivered_orders = 0  then 0 end as 
scan_percent
```

So if there's 4 orders and 3 are scanned, it will return 75. I want it to return 75%. I have tried concatenating it with || '%' and || % after the "end", but Python treats the percentage as a placeholder and it says Tuples out of range because I don't have enough values. I have also tried playing along with using it as a placeholder and then putting '%' when I do cursor.execute(query, ('%')) but it says:

ValueError: unsupported format character

I have tried a few other things as well. I'm banging my head against the wall here and thought you smart people might know what I need to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ugly workaround: `...| chr(37) || ...` (it will avoid the need to quote/escape the percent sign)

Comment: You can escape a single `%` like `%%`, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `%%` for literal `%`. From the Psycopg [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

> When parameters are used, in order to include a literal `%` in the query
> you can use the `%%` string:
>
> ```
> >>> cur.execute("SELECT (%s % 2) = 0 AS even", (10,))       # WRONG
> >>> cur.execute("SELECT (%s %% 2) = 0 AS even", (10,))      # correct
> ```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for everyone's help. You guys are all amazing.